# Local Colab using

Tags: google-colaboratory

Does Colab get payment for the local runtime connection? I've notice that the resources left was showing $0.008 per hour. And also is it possible that Colab will reset my session after 12 hours of activity? It's so uncomfortable when the model's training interrupts.

I need your hints about effective integration the PC and Google colab.

Comment: The fact is that Google does not reset the computing resources it has appropriated for you. You may finish that resources in a couple of hours. It is something like charging your Sim-Card.